# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ ... Reason: image not found with a simple Hello world applicat

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am running into some trouble when trying to use SwiftCSV using CocoaPods and following the [basic instructions](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html).

After creating the simple Hello world console application for OS X from the template in XCode 7.3.1, I opened a terminal window and navigated to the project folder and issued a `pod init`

I then edited Podfile by adding the line below in the target section:

```
  pod "SwiftCSV"
```

I then executed `pod install`, which completed successfully.

After loading the resulting .xcworkspace in XCode, when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftCSV.framework/Versions/A/SwiftCSV
  Referenced from: /Users/paolomarini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BundleGeneratorSwift-egsxgxpdiuvqrfddzyzcxnwltulk/Build/Products/Debug/BundleGeneratorSwift
  Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Note that I didn't specify a platform in Podfile as I can't figure out what the correct value is for OS X. The Podfile is as below:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BundleGeneratorSwift' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BundleGeneratorSwift
  pod "SwiftCSV"
end
```

Thanks,
Paolo

Comment: Try using `platform :osx, '10.11'` ...

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. I thought Pods were supposed to simplify things, yet the simplest use case imaginable doesn't seem to work.